# oAuth2.0 access_token with invalid format on Microsoft Identity Platform (/common/oauth2/v2.0/token)

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, access-token, identity

I'm trying to validate access_token retrieved by Microsoft Identity Platform when token request is done (/common/oauth2/v2.0/token), but always I get an invalid format error on any validator even online ones like jwt.io. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

My [post from a while back](https://authguidance.com/2017/12/06/azure-ad-api-token-validation) may help you to understand the validation process.

A couple of common things to check:

- Is there a 'nonce" field in the JWT header? If so it will fail validation and is not designed for your (custom) APIs to validate
- Does token validation work if you use the Azure AD v1 endpoints?

Comment: Thanks Gary for your answer, in my case the access_token is not valid cause the format isn't correct, it's like that token is encrypted by Microsoft and nobody can figure out what is behind it, I'm calling to common tenant and that token can be used for asking to any MS API (Graph Api) but if I have my own Resource Server and therefore I need to validate the token in every request, but with Microsoft one is not possible...

Comment: Ah - I see - had a closer look and it looks like they have some Microsoft specific handling going on. I would maybe start with [this Microsoft page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens). Looks like you may need to use one of the MS libraries they reference.

Comment: Those libraries are used for decoding valid JWT, on this case my access token is not using valid format so  it's not possible to get any claim... I think for common tenant the access token can be used only for adquiring data from MS API's, in the case that token is expired then Ms will give me that error message... Try to check yourself authorization code flow against common tenant, probably you get the same than me.